# CCNode override draw() method not working

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, overriding, draw

I want to draw some customized opengl elements, like `ccdrawline()`. According to cocos2d documentation, I should override `draw()` method to draw my stuff in my subclassed layer. However it is not working. While if I override the `visit()` method, I can see what I want to draw. I am puzzled about this and I am seeking for ideas for solving this.

I made it like this:

```
- (void)draw
{
  [super draw];
  CGPoint a = ccp(0,0);
  CGPoint b = ccp(480,320);
  ccDrawLine(a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct and it should work. But I vaguely remember that draw isn't called for CCLayer classes. Either way, draw or visit are virtually the same method, so just use whichever works.

Comment: Sorry for confirming this so late. You are right, I made a ccdrawline () test both on a layer and a node. Node's draw() methods works whereas layer's not. Thanks for the help~

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are missing the methods that tell how to draw the line? Worth a shot.

```
// Set color
glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

// Set line width
glLineWidth(6.0f);
```